# How to run chrome_prolog with XAMPP?

Tags: php, symfony, prolog, inference-engine

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning about logic programming with **PHP**.

I have found an interesting Prolog interpreter, **chrome_prolog** (https://github.com/crcx/chrome_prolog).

To know more about PHP, I am trying to run this code with **XAMPP 1.7.3**, on **Windows XP**. But, I failed.

1. When I run `PrologTest.php`, they show:

   ```
   Fatal error: Class '**PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase**' not found in **D:\XAMPP\htdocs\PrologTest.php** on line **10**
   ```
2. I don't want use **PHPUnit**, **Symfony**... and other frameworks. Because, I am **not good at PHP**, so I do **not want to use them**.

Can you help me to **solve error**, **remove framework** ... to make it to be **pure in PHP only**? And, please explain to help me know more?

---

If you have found a good **inference engine** (whose syntax likes **Prolog**) which is written in **pure PHP**, please introduce it for me!

Comment: see [Prolog](https://github.com/Trismegiste)

Comment: @CapelliC, This post must be **closed**. The *Stack Overflow* is **not** a *coding service*.